# Delphi TClientDataSet, maximum number of fields per index

Tags: delphi, indexing, delphi-2007, tclientdataset

I have a simple Delphi (2007) procedure that given a TDataSet and a (sub)list of fields returns a new TClientDataSet with the **distinct values** from the given TDataSet.

This works quite well.

In my proc I used the TClientDataSet index to populate the distinct values.
It was fast and easy.

The problem is that TClientDataSet index support at **maximum 16** fields.
If you add more of them they will be silently ignored.

I need more than 16 fields in the dataset (and thus in the index).

Is there any solution? Some hack?
Maybe some open source library to use as workaround?

I'm working offline so I must do it in memory. The size of the dataset is not *huge*

Comment: Can you delete each index after processing it before adding new indexes?

Comment: What I'm imagining is that you have a TDataset, and you want to remove the duplicates. To do it, you've set up an index in a TClientDataset, and you're simply copying everything, relying on the index to detect and discard duplicate rows. Am I right? Wouldn't it be easier and more direct to `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table`?

Comment: @RobKennedy Yes, I want to remove the duplicates. Actually create a new dataset without duplicates and with less fields.
I'm detached from database. That's why I cannot run a SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: @MikeW I don't undestand your question. In my proc I need to create just one index. For example my inital dataset has 10 fields. I need to do a distinct on 5 fields; so I create a new dataset with 5 fields and one index on this 5 fields.

Comment: Why the downvote? I did my research on the subject. Please, tell me your reasons

Comment: @Jako: Sorry, I misread your intentions as creating one index per field.  At this point I like SilentD's answer.

Comment: @MikeW you are welcome. I would go for SilentD answer. I'm reluctant to convert all my types to string.

Comment: @Jako: Instead of changing your data types I'd think you would want to add a new calculated field with a fieldkind of fkInternalCalc. In the OnCalcFields event handler just loop through each of the original columns concatenating a string.  You could even use DataSet.Fields[i].AsString to do the conversion for you.

Comment: Is the 16 field constraint as per the cursor? Because I don't see it in 'TCustomClientDataSet.SetIndex'.. Or is this related with 31 byte IndexName limit?

Comment: @MikeW I meant to convert the values to strings. Never wanted (for example) to change a TIntegerField to TStringField

Comment: @SertacAkyuz for example I have a TClientDataSet with 20 fields (f1,f2,...,f20) than a create and index, through IndexDefs, and Fields prop with the fields f1,f2,...f17; actually the index creation will silently ignore the last field (f17) due to constant DsIntf.pas.MAXKEYFIELDS=16. You can see the behaviour in DBClient.pas in TCustomClientDataSet.EncodeIndexDesc proc (line 3261 in my delphi 2007 version)

Comment: Changing the MAXKEYFIELDS and including available pas (DB.pas, DBClient.pas, DsIntf.pas) for recompiling will not fix this because TClientDataSet implementation is not available as source; it's invoked through an interface

Comment: can't you replace cds with say kbmmt or any other dataset free from such restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're needing to get distinct occurrences of records across more than 16 fields and you want to use an index to keep things fast you'll need to consider concatenating some of those fields.  For example:

Test Field                 Field 1   Field 2   Field 3   Field 4
Apple~Banana~Carrot~Donut  Apple     Banana    Carrot    Donut

Create you index on the Test Field.

You might need to create multiple test fields if the total length of your other fields exceeds the maximum length of a text field.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was wondering some other solution because I have many different field types (floating, date time). I'm going to wait if some other hint comes up

Comment: You don't need to convert all of your existing fields to text fields.  When you create the "Test Field" you'll want that to be a text representation of your integer fields.

Comment: Never wanted to, as I pointed out to MikeW. My concern is on the process of getting the right text representation and concatenation. Beside my concern I'm going for this solution and try to spot any side effect

Answer (score 0):

You could swap out the TClientDataSet for a TjvCsvDataset from JVCL.  It can be used as a pure  "in memory dataset" replacement for Client Data Sets, without any need to read or write any CSV files on disk.

It is not quite like Client Data Set in design. I am not sure what benefit all these "Indexes" in a client data set offer you, other than that you can't have a field without an index definition, but in the case that this is all you need, you can set the TJvCsvDataSet.FieldDef property = 'Field1,Field2,.....FieldN' and then open the dataset and add as many rows as you like to the dataset.  It is practically limited to the amount of memory you can address in a 32 bit process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Warren P and for pointing me to TjvCsvDataset. I'm not sure I've comprehended what are you referring with 'all these indexes'; I need only one index (the primary key if you prefer) that helps me to compute the distinct values from the original (big, with duplicated values) dataset. I've looked JvCsvData.pas (found some nice comment of yours through the source :) and checked the internal algorithm: the implementation of InternalFindByKey does a sequential scan and does not uses a index. I think this should be not as fast as TClientDataset approach.

Comment: You are correct, JvCsvDataSet is not internally indexed. However nothing stops you from subclassing it and building indexes if you want to.   (A simple dictionary object per index, would provide a fast indexed lookup on field values,  ie, 'TextValue1' --> Row3.). Heck nothing stops you from EXTERNALLY indexing a ClientDataSet either.